# Native "Modal ActivityIndicator with Message" component

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Does anyone know if these are native components in Android/iOS? Or are they custom built. I see them frequently so I was thinking they were native.

I was planning on doing my first native module so was looking for some ideas. It is a modal `<ActivityIndicator>` with message. Is this a native component? If it is may you please share the name of these components I was hoping to write my first native module using them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be easily done without native, with `<Modal />`.

Comment: Yes @Val I understand that, but I was looking for a simple native component to learn writing my first rn native module.